# How to test an AngularJS filter with dependency?

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine

I want to test an AngularJS custom filter that has another filter dependency on it. How could I accomplish that?

My filter looks like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .filter('addressLocations', function($filter) {
    return function(input, startFromIndex) {
      var arr = angular.copy(input);
      if (startFromIndex) {
        arr = arr.splice(startFromIndex);
      }

      var locations = '';
      angular.forEach(arr, function(address) {
        locations += $filter('location')(address) + '<br>';
      });

      return locations;
    };
  });
```

And my Jasmine test looks currently like that:

```
describe('addressLocations', function () {

  var filter;
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(addressLocations) {
    // ??? how to inject $filter into `addressLocations` ???
    filter = addressLocations;
  }));

  it('should filter correctly', function() {
    var input = [{
      city: 'Karlsruhe',
      country: 'Germany'
    }, {
      city: 'Berlin',
      country: 'Germany'
    }, {
      city: 'Stuttgart',
      country: 'Germany'
    }, {
      city: '',
      country: 'Germany'
    }, {
      city: '',
      country: ''
    }];
    expect( filter(input, 1) ).toEqual('Berlin, Germany<br>Stuttgart, Germany<br>Germany<br>Unknown');

  });
});
```

I know that the above code is more an integration test, but if I know how to inject dependencies in filters, I would inject a mock function to just test the unit, not the dependencies on it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need to manually inject $filter into addressLocations. Angular does the injection for you.

Answer (score -2):

I dont understand youre question, but to test the filter you should inject $filter not addressLocations

```
var filter;

beforeEach(module('myApp'));

beforeEach(inject(function(_$filter_) {
    filter = _$filter_;
 }));
```

....

```
expect( filter('addressLocations')(input, 1) )..
```

read more: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing Filter testing